# Which syntax options/language features did Scala remove over time (and why)?

Tags: scala, programming-languages, syntax, language-design, language-features

The title pretty much sums up my question.

The deprecation and removal of case class inheritance is a pretty new one, and I wonder which things got removed/substantially changed before that. I remember something about `val` in for loops and a different name for `object` as well as some `requires` keyword.

I would love to see code examples of how things were used/how they were replaced later, with an actual version when it happened and with a rationale why!

**PS: One item per answer seems to be a good idea!**

Comment: Many syntax changes are listed in the appendix of the [ScalaReference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was possible in Scala 2.7 to declare things of type `int` (no capital "I"). Since Scala does not support the idea of primitive values and tries to be as consistent with everything as far as it can, this "feature" is deprecated.

Comment: Afaik most community members didn't like the fact that some types started with a lowercase and some with uppercase, they "standardized" around uppercase around 2.8 ...

Answer (score 5):

Case class inheritance was a short-lived feature: It was introduced in 2.7, deprecated in 2.8/2.9 and finally removed in 2.10.

Example:

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
case class Bar extends Foo(42, 43)
```

The problem was that the automatically supplied equality implementations didn't really work in the face of inheritance, therefore this feature was removed.

Removing case class inheritance has also a good effect:
It will allow supplying better typed `product***` methods by inheriting the concrete `ProductN` trait:

```
val f = Foo(1,2).productIterator
f: Iterator[Any] = non-empty iterator // < 2.10
f: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator // 2.10 with -Xexperimental
```

Answer (score 3):

`requires` clause was deprecated in version 2.6.

```
trait A requires B {
  ...
}
```

is now written as:

```
trait A { self: B =>
  ...
}
```

I don't know the rationale behind this syntax change. I personally find the `requires` syntax a tad bit more readable.

Comment: I'm guessing here, that it didn't fit well with something like `trait A extends B requires C with D` and so on...You probably would need a lot of parenthesis there to make it clear what requires what and so on...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know all the details offhand, but there is an extremely detailed version history starting here:

http://www.scala-lang.org/node/155

Practically every item that went into every release is listed.  Many have links to JIRA tickets.

It might take a while to mine this data, but I suspect most of what you are looking for is there.  What you might not see in detail are the rationales for deprecation, but if a JIRA ticket is given or an indication of the feature is at least written down, a web search on that topic should lead to a discussion page and rationale.

Comment: There is also the "Scala language changes" page: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/43 What I'm looking for are some concrete examples and the rationale behind it...

Comment: This is a much better link then the one I put in my answer.  I looked at a couple removed features (`scala.compat.math` and `assertSame`) and it does look like finding out the reasons for deprecation in many cases is going to be hard.  So great idea soliciting input here!

Answer (score 2):

The for comprehensions used the keyword "val" before each generator. The next Scala version will no longer have this, but, presently, the following deprecated syntax is still accepted:

```
for (val i <- 1 to 10) yield i
```

This was just deemed unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: This still works in 2.10.0.r25323-b20110719020429 ...

Comment: @soc I might be mistaken, of course. But I could swear I saw the commit removing that. Well, I might be mistaken.

Comment: I could swear I saw it too, that's why I'm wondering ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Class literals (different from `classOf[]`) were removed from the language, but I couldn't figure out how they looked like, but probably like their Java equivalent `.class`.